# Explicitly display formula from a string variable in GLM

Tags: r, glm

I am writing a wrapper function that takes in a survival formula and transform it to a linear one. Because of some string manipulation, I would insert the eventual formula in as such :

```r
new_formula <- as.formula(paste(event, "~", "var1 + ", paste(all_vars, collapse=" + "), " + ", exposure))
linear <- glm(new_formula, data=x, family=poisson)
```

this would yield a glm object as such:

`Call:  glm(formula = new_formula, family = poisson, data = x)`

Is there a way to have the content of `new_formula` explicitly displayed in the results?

Comment: you can access the formula with `linear$formula`

Comment: also `formula(linear)`

Comment: @PabloRod thanks, Pablo, but I am looking for a way to display it in the results (i.e. along with all the coefficient estimates and etc) of the regression so the user of my function will be able to see the full formula instead of just `formula = new_formula`.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire, but I am looking for a way to display it in the results of the regression (i.e. along with all the coefficient estimates and etc) so the user of my function will be able to see the full formula instead of just `formula = new_formula`.

Comment: Oh, in the call that it displays? It captures that with `match.call`, so you either need to mess with the call after the fact, e.g. `x <- mpg ~ hp;
m <- glm(x, data = mtcars);
m$call$formula <- x`, or restructure the call before it's evaluated, e.g. `eval(bquote(glm(.(x), data = mtcars)))`. Neither is totally trivial.